# Grabbing sections of a text file - vb

Tags: vb.net

Probably kick-self simple, but this is defeating me.

I have a text file which I am looking to grab in sections and populates separate text boxes. This is what the list looks like:

data_file_name

<1st section>

data

data

data

<2nd section>

data

data

data

etc.

Is there a way for me to take each section? I thought of changing the delimiter in a TextReader but some of the data also has the <> signs in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code we could use to work with?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `system.io.file.readalllines(path)` to read the file into a string array. Then process the array in memory sequentially, or using `indexof`, for "<1st section>", etc. This one approach of about a dozen that will work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code to read each line of the file into a string. Then, you compare the string value to see if it looks like a new section. If so, do your new section code, else to your current section code

Dim reader as new streamreader(file.txt)

Dim inline as String

While reader.peek <> -1

inline = reader.readline

if inline.startswith("<") and inline.endswith(">") and inline.contains("section")

'do new section routine

else

'do current section routine

end if

end while

reader.close